# Difficulties with SQL query and COUNT

Tags: mysql-5.5, count

thanks in advnace for reading this. I'm not really good with SQL so please pardon any stupid mistake...

Here is the deal, I have four tables (i'm only going to give the basic fields, and dependencies between tables, for the sake of simplicity):

1. Company: companyId, companyName
2. User: userId, userName
3. Project: projectId, projectUserId, projectCompanyId, projectDate
4. Study: studyProjectId

The dependencies are like so:

- A project is for a client (projectUserId) and carried out by a company (projectCompanyId)
- There can be many studies for the same project, but each study is for one project (studyProjectId)

Here is the kind of request I'd like to write, but it doesn't work right now:

```
SELECT
    project.projectId,
    company.companyName,
    user.userName,
    COUNT( study.studyId ) AS numberStudies
FROM project, company, user, study
WHERE company.companyId = project.projectCompanyId,
AND user.userId = project.projectUserId,
AND study.studyProjectId = project.projectId
ORDER BY company.companyId, user.userId, project.projectDate;
```

It returns one record for which numberStudies equals the total number of studies. If I remove the `COUNT` from the `SELECT`, then I get the type of result I want, but without the column `numberStudies` (of course). Hoping you understand what I'm trying to get, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks again in advance :)

*EDIT: If possible, I'd like the request to show records even when `numberStudies` is 0.*

Comment: Add `GROUP BY company.companyName, user.userId, project.projectId` after the `WHERE`, before the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @ypercube Ok, now that's amazing! :) Could you please explain me why I need the `GROUP BY`, I'd really like to understand my mistake..

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Count is an aggregate function. They usually work together with other columns only when grouping by some (or all) of the  column(s). Please read: [MySQL Aggregate Functions](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx).

Comment: @Marian Thank you so much, this was faster than I expected :) You rock guys! If one of you cares to post an answer, I'll validate it right away.

Comment: Actually, I have another question: how can I get the request to show me records for which the count is 0; currently, it seems that they do not show up in the final result..

Comment: Why is a lot of the answer here in the comments?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek Good question :) Nobody wrote a complete answer yet, and I guess the original post was too easy for the guys who commented ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments, you need a `GROUP BY` clause when you want to have aggregate results (like it seems you want: "Number of Studies per project, company and user"). So, the first thing to do is add:

```
GROUP BY project.projectId, company.companyName, user.userName
```

Notice that the three columns are exactly the three that you have (unaggregated) in the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT
    project.projectId,
    company.companyName,
    user.userName,
    COUNT(study.studyId) AS numberStudies
FROM project, company, user, study
WHERE company.companyId = project.projectCompanyId,
  AND user.userId = project.projectUserId,
  AND study.studyProjectId = project.projectId
GROUP BY project.projectId, company.companyName, user.userName
ORDER BY company.companyId, user.userId, project.projectDate ;
```

This will show what you want but there are still a few issues:

- First, you are using the old (SQL-89) syntax of implicit joins with the conditions in the `WHERE` clause. This syntax is not deprecated but the new (well, 20 years old SQL-92) syntax with the `JOIN` keyword has several advantages.
- We can add aliases for the tables for readability.
- There may be two companies or users with same name so we should group by their IDs, not only their names.
- One advantage of explicit `JOIN` syntax is that it's easy to have results when there are no rows to join (as you want to show when there is no studies for a project). Just `LEFT JOIN` the `study` table.

So, the query becomes:

```
    SELECT
        p.projectId,
        c.companyName,
        u.userName,
        COUNT(s.studyId) AS numberStudies
    FROM 
        project AS p
      JOIN 
        company AS c  ON c.companyId = p.projectCompanyId
      JOIN 
        user AS u     ON u.userId = p.projectUserId
      LEFT JOIN 
        study AS s    ON s.studyProjectId = p.projectId
    GROUP BY 
        c.companyId,
        u.userId,
        p.projectId, 
        c.companyName,  u.userName
    ORDER BY 
        c.companyId, 
        u.userId, 
        p.projectDate ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really, for these lucid explanations and solution! :)

Comment: Why did you group by companyName and userName?

Answer (score 0):

you probably need a LEFT JOIN between study and project

Comment: Yes, actually that's what I dig on the web (at least one of the ways), but I can't get the request right yet..